# Scope of constraints in Rails 4 routes

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible in Rails 4 to create a scope of constraints as described in [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5548#issuecomment-5806078)?

### routes.rb

```
scope format: true, constraints: { format: 'json' } do
  get '/bar' => "bar#index_with_json"
end
```

The error I'm getting is

```
NoMethodError (undefined method 'source' for "json":String):
  config/routes.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, format type must be in slashes:

### routes.rb

```
scope format: true, constraints: { format: /json/ } do
  get '/bar' => "bar#index_with_json"
end
```

Comment: Although it does not seem to work like in Rails 3 so I'll use a before action as described in [Single-Page application with Rails 3 and AngularJS](http://bettysteger.com/single-page-application-with-rails-3-and-angularjs/)